# Passing array in function to sum its elements

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am very new at C. 
I'm trying to do a little piece of code where the user gets to enter 5 integers.
They get added in an array and the array passed in a function to sum all its elements. But i'm getting a bunch of errors back that I don't quite understand.

this is the piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int array[5];
    int index;
    int sum;
    //Function declaration.
    int sumArr(int arr[]);


    for (index = 0; index <= 4; index++)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &array[index]);
    }

    sum  = sumArr(array, 5);

    printf("The total sum of the integers contained in the array is: %d", sum);


//Function to summ the values sored in the array.

int sumArr(int arr[])
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
}
```

And this is the errors I get when I compile:
I don't understand why I get "static declaration of ‘sumArr’ follows non-static declaration", even after declaring what datatype holds.

```
test3.c: In function ‘main’:
 test3.c:22:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘sumArr’
   sum  = sumArr(array, 5);
   ^
 test3.c:12:5: note: declared here
 int sumArr(int arr[]);
     ^
test3.c:31:6: error: static declaration of ‘sumArr’ follows non-static   declaration
  int sumArr(int arr[])
      ^
 test3.c:12:5: note: previous declaration of ‘sumArr’ was here
  int sumArr(int arr[]);
      ^
```

Comment: 1st of all you might like to move the definition 'sumArr()` *out of* `main()`'s scope.

Comment: Your braces are mixed up for `main`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't the second argument in your function. You should do this:

```
int sumArr(int arr[], int s)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < s; ++i)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Better do `..., size_t s)` and inside `sumArr()` use `size_t i;` instead of `int i;`.

Answer (score 1):

> test3.c:22:2: error: too many arguments to function ‘sumArr’

This pretty much tells you what the problem is. `sumArr` is defined as

```
int sumArr(int arr[])
{
...
}
```

Yet you are trying to call it with two arguments: the array, and the integer 5. To fix this, change the function above to

```
int sumArr(int arr[], int variableName)
{
...
}
```

> test3.c:31:6: error: static declaration of ‘sumArr’ follows non-static   declaration

Both the function prototype (the single line `int sumArr(int arr[]);` which will need to be changed to match the above change) and definition (where you actually provided the function code) for `sumArr()` are currently inside `main()`. Move them outside, put the prototype *above* the `main()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this.

int sumArr( int arr[], int size );

You are passing 5 as 2nd argument.